# Winsock 2 discovering Bluetooth devices only showing previously paired devices

Tags: bluetooth, device, winsock

I am currently trying to use the WINSOCK 2 API in order to discover available Bluetooth devices near by. I am using code which is based on a Microsoft example which can be found [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Connection-e3263296).

I am mainly using WSALookupServiceNext to iterate through the available devices. The issue is that I only get a list of previous paired Bluetooth devices, and I am not seeing any other devices. I added some code in order to print device information:

```
*********************
Winsock search started!
*********************

Device #:1
Device name:MagicBox II
Device connected: 0
Device remembered: 1
Device authenticated: 1
Remote Bluetooth device is 0x00025b3dc371, server channel = 0
Local Bluetooth device is 0x84ef18b8460a, server channel = 0
Device #:2
Device name:Mpow Flame
Device connected: 0
Device remembered: 1
Device authenticated: 1
Remote Bluetooth device is 0x501801101c68, server channel = 0
Local Bluetooth device is 0x84ef18b8460a, server channel = 0
Device #:3
Device name:WH-1000XM2
Device connected: 0
Device remembered: 1
Device authenticated: 1
Remote Bluetooth device is 0x702605aba41d, server channel = 0
Local Bluetooth device is 0x84ef18b8460a, server channel = 0
Device #:4
Device name:Magicbuds
Device connected: 0
Device remembered: 1
Device authenticated: 1
Remote Bluetooth device is 0x5017032a701b, server channel = 0
Local Bluetooth device is 0x84ef18b8460a, server channel = 0
```

Here is the corresponding code section, ( I did call WSAStartup beforehand):

```
void WSALookupAvailableDevices(void)
{
    WSAQUERYSET     wsaQuery{};
    LPWSAQUERYSET   pwsaResults{};
    HANDLE          hLookup{};

    CSADDR_INFO     *pAddrInfo{};
    SOCKADDR_BTH    *pBtSockRemote{}, 
                    *pBtSockLocal{};

    char    buffer[4096] = {};
    int     nDevicesFound = 1;
    DWORD   swSize = sizeof(buffer);
    DWORD   flags = LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RES_SERVICE | LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RETURN_TYPE;

    /*Preparing the query set*/
    wsaQuery.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
    wsaQuery.dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);


    if (WSALookupServiceBegin(&wsaQuery, flags, &hLookup) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"Shit something went wrong! error: %d!\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return;
    }

    wprintf(L"*********************\n");
    wprintf(L"Winsock search started!\n");
    wprintf(L"*********************\n\n");


    /*Preparing the queryset return buffer*/
    pwsaResults = (LPWSAQUERYSET)buffer;
    pwsaResults->dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
    pwsaResults->dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);

    while (WSALookupServiceNext(hLookup, flags, &swSize, pwsaResults) == NO_ERROR)
    {
        pAddrInfo       = (CSADDR_INFO*)pwsaResults->lpcsaBuffer;
        pBtSockRemote   = (SOCKADDR_BTH*)(pwsaResults->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr);
        pBtSockLocal    = (SOCKADDR_BTH*)(pwsaResults->lpcsaBuffer->LocalAddr.lpSockaddr);

        wprintf(L"Device #:%d\n", nDevicesFound);
        wprintf(L"Device name:%s\n", pwsaResults->lpszServiceInstanceName);
        wprintf(L"Device connected: %d\n", (pwsaResults->dwOutputFlags & BTHNS_RESULT_DEVICE_CONNECTED));
        wprintf(L"Device remembered: %d\n", (pwsaResults->dwOutputFlags & BTHNS_RESULT_DEVICE_REMEMBERED)>0);
        wprintf(L"Device authenticated: %d\n", (pwsaResults->dwOutputFlags & BTHNS_RESULT_DEVICE_AUTHENTICATED)>0);
        wprintf(L"Remote Bluetooth device is 0x%04x%08x, server channel = %d\n",
            GET_NAP(pBtSockRemote->btAddr), GET_SAP(pBtSockRemote->btAddr), pBtSockRemote->port);
        wprintf(L"Local Bluetooth device is 0x%04x%08x, server channel = %d\n",
            GET_NAP(pBtSockLocal->btAddr), GET_SAP(pBtSockLocal->btAddr), pBtSockLocal->port);

        nDevicesFound++;

    }
    WSALookupServiceEnd(hLookup);
    wprintf(L"\n");
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you change your use of `flags` to pass *only* `LUP_CONTAINERS` to `WSALookupServiceBegin()`, and to omit `LUP_CONTAINERS` from  `WSALookupServiceNext()`?

Comment: Yes, issue is still persistent after changing `WSALookupServiceBegin()' flags to `LUP_CONTAINERS` and omitting it for `WSALookupServiceNext()`.

Comment: It does not matter until you provide LUP_FLUSHCACHE flag which says to driver exewcute discovering. Any other flags only change returned information set. And yes, you do not need LUP_RES_SERVICE (it queries services from remote device). And better to read device's name later because MS stack resolves device's name later, after discovering completed. For name it is better to use WM_DEVICECHANGE message to be sure you get device's name. However it depends on requirements but for new just found devices name will appears as empty in 99%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LUP_FLUSHCACHE is what you need. And yes, it will always return paired device (in addition to discovered). I mean that if device paired WSALookup returns it in the list even it is not available (turned off or out of range).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wsalookupservicebegin-for-device-inquiry

```
DWORD   flags = LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RES_SERVICE | LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_FLUSHCACHE;
```

But the best way to discover devices is to use this flags set.

```
DWORD   flags = LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_FLUSHCACHE;
```

Also it is good idea to provide additional information (BTH_QUERY_DEVICE) so you can set discovering timeout and other params

```
BTH_QUERY_DEVICE qDev;
qDev.LAP = 0;
qDev.length = bTimeout; // Timeout in seconds
BLOB Blb;
Blb.cbSize = sizeof(BTH_QUERY_DEVICE);
Blb.pBlobData = (PBYTE)&qDev;
QuerySet.lpBlob = &Blb;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/windows/desktop/api/ws2bth/ns-ws2bth-_bth_query_device

After discovering completed (please note that WSALookupServiceBegin takes time (blocks) until discovering finished) you can use BluetoothGetDeviceInfo to get extended information such as device's name and other info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothgetdeviceinfo

You should know that because of some Bluetooth limitations name resolution can be executed only after discovering completed. And this operation may take time. So if you call to BluetoothGetDeviceInfo  right after discovering completed you can still get empty device name for new discovered devices (devices that was not previouslt discovered).

There is not easy way to resolve this issue except switch to WinRT API or wait for some time before reading device name. You also can use WM_DEVICECHANGE message to get notification about device name resolution

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wm-devicechange-messages

And there is one more problem: MS stack always returnsd paired devices during discovering even they are not available.

Comment: LUP_FLUSHCACHE  does exactly answered your question. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wsalookupservicebegin-for-device-inquiry) It seems you did not read answer but just looked for known words.

Comment: So I changed the `flags` for `WSALookupServiceBegin()` to only `LUP_CONTAINERS` and added `LUP_FLUSHCACHE ` to the `flags` of `WSALookupServiceNext()`. I am still having the issue of not seeing any devices besides the already paired ones.

Comment: It looks you did not follow the link. There are lot of usefull information. Especially about flags. You need LUP_CONTAINERS - to query for devices, LUP_FLUSHCACHE - to execute discovering instead of returning just paired and one of other flag to get information about device: LUP_RETURN_ADDR or LUP_RETURN_BLOB

Comment: And of course LUP_FLUSHCACHE flag must be set for WSALookupServiceBegin that does callect information. WSALookupServiceNext only iterates through already callected list and actualy does nothing internally. So with only LUP_CONTAINERS you get list of only paired devices/

Comment: Okay, so I did a test wit a different Bluetooth device (Samsung Tablet), which now shows up, but only if I set it explicitly to be visible to nearby devices. Is this always needed? I was assuming if I e.g. turn the BT of my phone on, I would be able to see it without going in to the settings and changing the visibility.

Comment: Yes of course. It is always needed. Bluetooth device (radio) may be in few states. The important is Discoverable and Connectable. If device is in Discoverable state (mode) it can be discovered by other devices. if device is in Connectable state it can be connected by other devices. Of course device can be in both states as well. Android devices when you turn Bluetooth ON are in connectable state. To swicth them into discoverable state you have to do some additional steps (depends on Android version).

Comment: Thanks for the response @MikePetrichenko! Just to get that straight, Connectable does not imply Discoverable as well. Is there a way in order to see devices which are only in Connectable using WINSOCK?

Comment: Of course no. There is no way to discover Bluetooth device if it is not in discoverable mode. And it does not matter WinSock or anything else. It is so by Bluetooth specification (design). Of course I do not talk about different discoverable modes. But in common way you can think abou it only as device is discoverable (can be discovered) or not (can not be discovered).